# Transform hash of arrays and/or scalars into an array of arrays of combinations of scalars

Tags: ruby, transformation

I feel this must be an easy problem for someone whereas I spent a surprising amount of time trying to find a solution and couldn't find one that I like.

I will not attempt to say in words what I need but just give some example inputs and their expected outputs as Rspec code:

The method would be:

```
def explode(hash)
  ...
end
```

And the spec:

```
describe '#explode' do
  it do
    expect(explode({:a => 1, :b => 2})).
      to eq [[:a, 1, :b, 2]]
  end

  it do
    expect(explode({:a => 1, :b => [2,3,4]})).
      to eq [
        [:a, 1, :b, 2],
        [:a, 1, :b, 3],
        [:a, 1, :b, 4]
      ]
  end

  it do
    expect(explode({:a => [1,2], :b => [3,4]})).
      to eq [
        [:a, 1, :b, 3],
        [:a, 2, :b, 3],
        [:a, 1, :b, 4],
        [:a, 2, :b, 4]
      ]
  end

  it do
    expect(explode({:a => 1, :b => [2,3], :c => [4,5,6]})).
      to eq [
        [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 4],
        [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 4],
        [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 5],
        [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 5],
        [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 6],
        [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 6]
      ]
  end
end
```

Solutions in languages other than Ruby also welcome.

Comment: Just out of interest, what was your approach?

Comment: Aside from over-complicated ideas that led to way too much code, the closest I got so far is similar to what you have here - firstly, convert all `:x => y` to `:x => [y]` and secondly, use the Cartesian product of the arrays. But I didn't get it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Array.html#method-i-product) seems like a good fit here.

```
h1 = {:a => 1, :b => 2}
h2 = {:a => 1, :b => [2,3,4]}
h3 = {:a => [1,2], :b => [3,4]}
h4 = {:a => 1, :b => [2,3], :c => [4,5,6]}

def explode hash
  a, *b = hash.transform_values { |v| [*v] }.values.unshift
  a.product(*b).map { |ar| hash.keys.zip(ar).flatten }.sort_by(&:last)
end

p explode h1  
 #[[:a, 1, :b, 2]]
p explode h2
 #[[:a, 1, :b, 2],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 3],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 4]]

p explode h3
 #[[:a, 1, :b, 3],
 # [:a, 2, :b, 3],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 4],
 # [:a, 2, :b, 4]]

p explode h4
 #[[:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 4],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 4],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 5],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 5],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 6],
 # [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 6]]
```

In order for my approach to work I had to remap the values so they are all arrays, which isn't ideal. But I still posted this answer as it may give you or others a starting point.

Comment: Actually, the ordering of the arrays is not important. That's fantastic, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array#product](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-product) twice.

```
def explode(hash)
  first, *rest = hash.map { |k,v| [k].product([*v]) }
  first.product(*rest).map(&:flatten)
end

h = { :a =>1, :b =>[2,3], :c =>[4,5,6] }    
explode h
  #=> [[:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 4], [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 5], [:a, 1, :b, 2, :c, 6], 
  #    [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 4], [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 5], [:a, 1, :b, 3, :c, 6]]
```

Note that, for `h` above,

```
first, *rest = h.map { |k,v| [k].product([*v]) }
  #=> [[[:a, 1]], [[:b, 2], [:b, 3]], [[:c, 4], [:c, 5], [:c, 6]]]
first
  #=> [[:a, 1]]
rest
  #=> [[[:b, 2], [:b, 3]], [[:c, 4], [:c, 5], [:c, 6]]]
```

and

```
first.product(*rest)
  #=> [[[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 4]], [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 5]],
  #    [[:a, 1], [:b, 2], [:c, 6]], [[:a, 1], [:b, 3], [:c, 4]],
  #    [[:a, 1], [:b, 3], [:c, 5]], [[:a, 1], [:b, 3], [:c, 6]]]
```

Observe that `[*1] #=> [1]`, `[*:a] #=> [:a]` and `[*[1,2]] #=> [1,2]`, meaning that `[*k]` converts a scalar `k` to an array containing that element and `[*k]` equals `k` if `k` is an array.

Answer (score 1):

Because I had to get this to work for Ruby < 2.4 (where there is no transform_values) - and also, because I don't need the arrays sorted, I ended up with:

```
def explode(hash)
  hash.each do |k,v|
    if not hash[k].is_a?(Array)
      hash[k] = [hash[k]]
    end
  end
  a, *b = hash.values.unshift
  a.product(*b).map do |arr|
    hash.keys.zip(arr).flatten
  end
end
```

Comment: Nice one. Also note `if  !` is equivalent to `unless` :)